# Encrypt / Decrypt - Encode / Decode PHP Equvilent to JAVA

Tags: java, php, encryption, encoding

Can anyone explain the PHP code and give me hints on how to port the code in Java?

Here is the PHP code:

```
function decode_string($encoded_string, $key) {
    $decoded = rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), base64_decode($encoded_string), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))), "\0");

    return $decoded;
}
```

Comment: Given that you are good in one programming language it should be fairly obvious what this snipped is doing. Any function calls that aren't obvious [can be goggled](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-decrypt.php). It should be noted that the person who wrote this code has no understanding of cryptography and is using the same IV for encrypting multiple items - this renders the encryption somewhat useless.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I'll bite, but I'll let you do the coding:

- `rtrim(x, "\0")`: removes the braindead zero padding (0..15 bytes of zeros) that PHP employs, this to make the plaintext X times the block size, required for CBC. You'll have to program this yourself as it is not present in Bouncy Castle - so don't use any padding mode. Just remove the zero valued bytes at the right of the decrypted plaintext.
- `mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256)`: probably somebody thought that this means AES-256, which it isn't. It is Rijndael with a block size of 256 bits. You need the Bouncy Castle libs in Java to decrypt that non-standardized part of the cipher
- `MD5($key)` somebody needed 256 bits of key material and thought that the hex encoding of the MD5 value over a password was good enough. It isn't, as it only provides half of the entropy (2 hex chars per byte). That and the fact that MD5 is not a password hashing function makes this disingenuous at best
- `base64_decode($encoded_string)`: well, expect base 64 encoding, which is alright *if* the ciphertext needed to be present as ASCII compatible text
- `MCRYPT_MODE_CBC`: that's OK, but as PHP is mainly used as a web language, I expect the message to be vulnerable to padding oracle / plain text oracle attacks, and you should of course expect any alteration of the ciphertext to be undetectable
- `md5(md5($key))`: applying MD5 twice does not make this any more safe than a zero IV and don't forget the hexadecimal conversion performed by each of these functions; fortunately that does mean that the IV is at least 256 bits instead of 128 bits

So you need to use:

```
new BufferedBlockCipher(new RijndaelEngine(256))
```

in the lightweight API of Bouncy Castle.

Happy coding, you're good in Java, so this should be a breeze. Upgrade away from this utter crap ASAP.

Comment: Note to second point: I guess Rijndael-256 is [standardized](http://csrc.nist.gov/archive/aes/rijndael/Rijndael-ammended.pdf) as an extension (12.). It's just that javax doesn't provide an implementation for it.

Comment: @ArtjomB. No, Rijndael-256 is well defined by the authors - that's not the problem, it has not been standardized by NIST as the "Advanced Encryption Standard". Note that you are pointing to the *proposal*.

Comment: Ok, *standarized* is a bit much. Is there a final version of Rijndael besides the proposal?

Comment: +1 for _Upgrade away from this utter crap_. This is an appalling abuse of cryptography.

Comment: @ArtjomB Not of Rijndael but AES is standardized in FIPS 197 available on the NIST website.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ... I was actually confused with `AES` and `RIJNDAEL`. Now I got the answer that I was actually looking for. Best part of answer: `new BufferedBlockCipher(new RijndaelEngine(256))`.

Comment: The best way of saying thanks on SO is to upvote/accept an answer!